# could connect to kafka instance in node?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I have two computer running in the local network, one computer is installed with kafka instance on 192.168.1.3:9092. In another computer a short test program is running a kafka client to connect kafka instance and subscribe a topic.

my kafka-node is latest version, v4.1.3

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const bp = require('body-parser');
//const config = require('./config');

try {
  const Consumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer;
  const client = new kafka.KafkaClient("kafkaHost: '192.168.1.3:9092'");
  let consumer = new kafka.Consumer(
    client,
    [{ topic: "dbserver1", partition: 0 }],
    {
      autoCommit: true,
      fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000,
      fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
      encoding: 'utf8',
      fromOffset: false
    }
  );
  consumer.on('message', async function(message) {
    console.log('here');
    console.log(
      'kafka-> ',
      message.value
    );
  })
  consumer.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
  });
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

The code is shown above. However the code is always telling me

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9092
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9092 }
```

why it is showing 127.0.0.1 not 192.168.1.3?

Comment: What did you set as the advertised listeners setting in the Kafka properties?

Comment: I am running kafka in docker: 
    docker run -it — name kafka -p 9092:9092 — link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka

I don't know the default  advertised listeners setting, what does it do?

Comment: It tells clients what address to connect to. You need more than a simple port forward

Comment: does this -p 9092:9092 tell the port to connect to?

Comment: No. All that does is forward the host network to the container. Your initial connection to the container works, it's returning a list of all other brokers (if you had any) back for future connections, and the default is 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you're running the Debezium Kafka docker container... From the Debezium Docker tutorial...

> If we wanted to connect to Kafka from outside of a Docker container, then we’d want Kafka to advertise its address via the Docker host, which we could do by adding `-e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=` followed by the IP address or resolvable hostname of the Docker host, which on Linux or Docker on Mac this is the IP address of the host computer (not `localhost`).

Sounds like your node code is not running in a container, or at least not on the same machine / Docker network

So you'll have to add `-e ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=192.168.1.3` to your docker run command